# How practical is it to live in Korea without a "Korean name"?

Tags: korean-culture, names

I got to a portion of my Korean homework that asked me to write my name "in Korean".  I thought that was really dumb, considering the widespread use of Roman letters in Korea.  But lo and behold, there's a surprising amount of posts on the internet of people asking how to make a Korean name.  Is there a practical reason for this? Or is it just koreaboo behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The widespread use of Roman letters does not mean that Koreans can pronounce non-Korean names properly. In addition, there are various languages that use Roman letters; how can a person distinguish them all? At least, I am not a genius to do so.

Making a Korean name is different from *writing your name in Korean*. You were asked to do the *latter*. Just by transcribing your name into Korean, you can help Koreans call you more accurately, type your name conveniently with Korean letters, and remember your original name.

One of my friends whose mother tongue is English has shown Koreans her name in Korean and it is just *the pronunciation of her name*. I would have never known how to read her name correctly if she had not written it in Korean. Now I know how to write her name in her mother tongue as well.

Comment: For instance, the name Christen might be 크리스텐, but as it is with names, it's yours...so go 크레지.